# PHP uses variables from a different section

Tags: php, web

I want to use variables from an different section of php on a web page. Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
<?php
$MyTitle = "Some Text";
?>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $MyTitle; ?></title>
</head>
<body>Hello world</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is **external instance** ? if its  just a file use `include`\`require`

Comment: It means a different section of code with the <?php ?>.

Comment: if its in the same file, the above will work fine

Comment: a PHP script is just a text file, I wouldn't call it an "instance"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [include()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). Here is an example of it:

**vars.php**

```
<?php

$color = 'green';
$fruit = 'apple';

?>
```

**test.php**

```
echo "A $color $fruit"; // A

include 'vars.php';

echo "A $color $fruit"; // A green apple

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables needs to be in 'scope' of the document you are trying to use the variables within.

### yourFile.php

```
<?php
$document = array('title'=>'My Test HTML Page!', 'author'=>'Test');
?>
```

### yourHtmlFile.php

```
<?php
include('yourFile.php');
?>
<h1>Welcome, <?= $document->title ?></h1>
<h2>Written By: <?= $document->author ?></h2>
```

In this example, I've used an array as I find it cleaner.